# PA, PP, KF, are any of these "Kindergarten"

Tags: school

I am not very familiar with the school system in the USA. I am trying to enroll my child for Kindergarten in the Beaverton, OR school district. Their online application makes me pick the "Entering Grade", and gives me a choice between:

- **PA**
- **PP**
- **KF**
- **01**
- **02**

...

- **12**

What would one expect "PA", "PP" and "KF" to mean, and does any of them seem to be Kindergarten? My kid is five years old, so this is all asked under the assumption that Kindergarten is the right grade for them. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KF` is the Kindergarten here; see for example [on this page](https://jacobwismer.beaverton.k12.or.us/about-us/newsletter), on the April 13, 2020 entry:

> To navigate to the Specials Class, look in the upper left corner. You should see your child’s name. If you click on his/her name, a list should appear below with your child’s classroom teacher and now you should see Specials Grade XX (KF for kindergarten, 01-05 for Grade 01-Grade 05).

Most likely, `PA` is PreK-AM, `PP` is Prek-PM, and `KF` is Kindergarten-Full Day.  Not all school districts have full day kindergarten; many have only half day for Kindergarten, and perhaps this school district used to have `KA` and `KP`, or else they use a standardized software.

And yes, Kindergarten would be the US grade a child who was 5 right now in most school districts (though verify in yours exactly what the age cutoff is, if they were born in August in particular).

Comment: I'd add, also, that this is quite late to be registering for Kindergarten - in my school district they've already made class assignments and such, and I'm sure in most; so be prepared for some difficulty registering now.  Also - learn how to get information from your school, whether that is introducing yourself to the secretary or something else; it's a vital thing as a parent to have an "in" at the school that can give you information quickly when you need it, and help you navigate the bureaucracy.